# Netbeans Become very Slow when pc are connected through internet

Tags: windows, firefox, netbeans, ide

i am using netbeans IDE 7.3.1 . but when ever i run a java web based project and connect internet to my pc, then my browser and netbeans IDE both become very slow . how can i resolve this issue ? is there any solution ? is there hardware issue regarding slowness ??

Comment: can any one ans there to answer this , i am really need help regarding this ....